# How can I pass select option value to a input type date

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, string, datetime

So I have a field for a date in database and I want to select a year in select option and pass the value of it to the year of the date, also I want to have a default month and day( 01/01 ) and the value of the option that I have selected will be the year.

How can I set a default month and day and pass the year value of the option to the year in date?

```
<select id="LastRenovationDate" name="LastRenovationDate">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Where do you want to set the default? On the client (then please remove C# and asp.net tags)

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you create a JavaScript [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), which can be created using separate day month and year components (see snippet). The date object can then be formatted to match your database's expected input.  However, exact the formatting needed would depend on the expected input for your database, which you have not provided.

```js
document.querySelector("#LastRenovationDate").onchange = function(){

    // selected value
    var select_val = this.value;
    
    // enter your date components
    var year = select_val,
    month = 0, // zeor indexed
    day = 1;
    
    var js_date_object = new Date( year , month , day );
    console.log( js_date_object );
    
    // Then, format js_date_object to match your database
}
```

```html
<select id="LastRenovationDate" name="LastRenovationDate">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: The OP doesn't need a Date object, they just need a string that is the selected year with the string "-01-01" appended, something like `this.value + '-01-01'`.